# Scale svg without changing filter effects

Tags: svg

We need large screenshot of html which contains svg text with some effects. So we are zooming html in chrome and taking screenshots.

But svg filter effects get changed on html zooming. We need svg effects same in all scale.

Please refer attached screen shots.
Image with scale:

[image: Image with scale]

Image without scale:

[image: Image without scale]

Comment: No, Firefox also has same issue.

Comment: Then add your markup to the question so we can see what's happening. What we need is a [mcve] here.

Comment: sample code here:http://codepen.io/nokiss/pen/ONOJNz

Comment: In the question itself please.

Answer (score 0):

[feSpecularLighting](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/filters.html#feSpecularLightingElement) is resolution dependent, you'd have to manipulate the kernelUnitLength property on each zoom step to cancel out the resolution dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. We tried kernelUnitLength , but the problem is still there, is there any suggestion.

Comment: That's all there is other than avoiding the filter altogether. You changed the kernelUnitLength dynamically on each zoom step?

Comment: no, i just added kernelUnitLength=1 as feSpecularLighting  attribute. and then zoomed.

Comment: That's not what my answer says you need to do though, is it?

Comment: i tried different values in kernelUnitLength , but there is no change in filter effect.

Comment: That's odd, Firefox certainly implements support.

Comment: Thanks a lot. kernelUnitLength is working in latest Firefox.  But filter effect is not good to see in Firefox. Same effects are rendered differently in both browsers.